# @JsonPoperty can not get nested value

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I have:

```
    {
        "id": "2021-04-03T15-SV_Waldhof_Mannheim--Zwickau",
        "something": {
            "id": "12",
            "value": 1.5
        }
    }
```

I want get value: 1.15, and store it in my variable.
How can i do it with @JsonPropety?

```
    @JsonProperty("something[value}") //how to do it correctly?
    private float value;
```

How i parse JSON:

```
restTemplate.exchange(MY_GET_REQUEST, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyEntity>>(){})
```

I will be grateful for any help, if you know identical topics - just send link

**UPDATED**
something.value does not work

The same problem with unpacking, such as:

```
 @JsonProperty("something")
    public void setLng(Map<String, Float> coordinates) {
        this.value= (Float.parseFloat(coordinates.get("value")));
 }
```

Also does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use custom deserializer for your response. In this case you able to populate any target DTO in any way. Here you could find example of custom [deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization#on-mapper)
2. Use the same structure for your DTO as in response (with sub object) and add additional method in root DTO to access this value. But in this case it could produce side effects on serialization (for example, additional field in root DTO)

**UPDATE**
Such configuration is working for me

```
    public static class Obj {
        @JsonProperty("id")
        String id;
        Float value;

        @JsonProperty("something")
        public void value(Map<String, Object> obj) {
            this.value = Float.parseFloat(obj.get("value").toString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there any option without deserializer? Can i make it with annotations ?

Comment: Answer was updated for setter method case.

Comment: I didn't saw that there was 2 levels of wrapping, not 1.
Thanks for help